# Automotive grade linux like apt-get and dkpg missing

Tags: linux, automotive-grade-linux

I am using a very light linux os for a customer (device with a touchscreen).
Both apt-get and dkpg are missing.
wget also missing.
Install linux again is not an option.
The device can be somethimes connected to the internet.

Plan is to install evemu so I can record touchscreen touch events and also replay touch events (some sort of automativ testing).

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Do you have a ssh connection? Compile evemu on another system and copy it?

Comment: have ssh connection, but don't know how to compile it as client has a weird custom linux distributuion, found a solution to record events using evtest, now I need to send touch screen tap at coodinates x y .